# Docker successfully builds image but it says created 6 days ago

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a custom image and tag it. I am using this command:

```
docker build -t chatbot:5 .
```

At the end it returns:

```
Successfully built f5fbad09c6ae
Successfully tagged chatbot:5
```

However, when i run the command `docker images` i see this line (among others):

```
chatbot             5                   f5fbad09c6ae        6 days ago          832MB
```

EDIT: I also see that different versions of this image have the same image id

Why it says created 6 days ago?

Comment: Were there any changes, or did the build use the cache entirely?

Comment: Yes, there were some changes

Comment: @MatejJ How does the accepted answer solve the reported issue? You said that you made some changes, built anew the image but practically the newly built image was the old one.

Comment: I had multiple versions of an old image built from cache. Before building a new one i also removed all previous versions of an image

Comment: What's in your `Dockerfile`? I found `RUN` commands exhibit this issue but `COPY` commands do not, as per: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34786

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `--no-cache` to rebuild

`docker build -t chatbot:5 . --no-cache`

If it still doesn't work, just remove the image first

`docker rmi chatbot:5`